# ##[error]ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cypress

I'm getting this error on azure pipelines while running cypress test cases.
Can anyone help in solving this error on host agent of Azure?

Error

> ##[error]Bash wrote one or more lines to the standard error stream.
> ##[error]ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0' ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function
> snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory ALSA
> lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings ALSA lib
> conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned
> error: No such file or directory ALSA lib
> confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name ALSA lib
> conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
> error: No such file or directory ALSA lib
> conf.c:5220:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
> directory ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM
> default
>
> ##[error]ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0' ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function
> snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory ALSA
> lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings ALSA lib
> conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned
> error: No such file or directory ALSA lib
> confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name ALSA lib
> conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
> error: No such file or directory ALSA lib
> conf.c:5220:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
> directory ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM
> default

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue on Azure Pipelines while running test cases using Cypress, Just change your browser from electron to chrome or any other browser.